# Как мне использовать метод append() с Json?

Tags: python, json

Так вот, у меня должен быть Json такого типа ->

```
{
    "guild_id": [ #здесь id гильдии первой
        {
            "role_name": "name",
            "role_id": "id"
        },
        {
            "role_name": "name",
            "role_id": "id"
        }
    ],

    "guild_id1": [ #здесь id гильдии второй
        {
            "role_name": "name",
            "role_id": "id"
        },
        {
            "role_name": "name",
            "role_id": "id"
        }
    ]
}
```

У гильдий есть список ролей-модеров которые добавляются с помощью команды. У ролей в свою очередь есть имя и айдишник. Так вот я не понимаю, как создать такой Json с помощью Python.

Comment: так вам необходимо создать самому такой json, как в примере выше или все же как добавить в существующий?

Comment: нужно создать такого формата. Но и в последующем добавлять в существующий

Comment: ***Как мне использовать метод append() с Json?*** - это тогда для чего?

Comment: Мне не же потом добавлять придется с помощью этого метода (скорее всего)

Comment: Создайте словарь в питоне, это же просто, словарь потом легко переводится в json туда-обратно.

Answer (score 0):

Делается это легко, но без проверки не обойтись:

```
rolejs = load_json('jsons\moderRoles.json') #load_json Это сторонняя функция

if str(guild_id) not in rolejs: 
    rolejs[str(guild_id)] = [{'role_id': 'id', 'role_name': 'name'}] #обратите внимание на квадратные скобки. Здесь они присутствуют ибо мы создаем список
else:
    rolejs[str(guild_id)].append({'role_id': 'id', 'role_name': 'name'}) #в будучи созданный список добавляем новый элемент. Квадратных скобок нет

write_json('jsons\moderRoles.json', rolejs)
```

guild_id, id и name - их значение присваивается "за кадром"

Comment: Чтобы избежать проверки -- внутри load_json превратите ваш словарь в Defaultdict со значением по умолчанию []. Тогда весь if/else уйдет в ```rolejs[str(guild_id)].append({'role_id': 'id', 'role_name': 'name'})```